# Is possible to column as Row using Linq and show on View?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a table with the name of Fuel and data show in table like

```
Name   | OrderDate | Qty
H&S1   | 1/1/2008  | 100
H&S1   | 1/2/2008  | 200
H&S1   | 2/2/2008  | 350
H&S2   | 2/28/2008 | 220
H&S2   | 3/12/2008 | 250
H&S2   | 3/15/2008 | 2150
```

and i want show like Result on **View**

```
Name| Jan- 2008 | Feb- 2008 | Mar - 2008| Total
1       | 100       | 350       |  250  | 700
2       | 200       | 220       | 2150  | 2170
```

and the **IActionResult** is

```
public IActionResult GetRes()
        {
            List<CustData> myList = GetCustData();

            var query = myList
                .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
                .Select(g => new {
                    CustId = g.Key,
                    Jan = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 1).Sum(c => c.Qty),
                    Feb = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 2).Sum(c => c.Qty),
                    March = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 3).Sum(c => c.Qty)
                });
            return View(myList);
        }
```

now i want to show this data on view 
can any one guide me how to display this format on View.
like this

```
Name| Jan- 2008 | Feb- 2008 | Mar - 2008| Total
1       | 100       | 350       |  250  | 700
2       | 200       | 220       | 2150  | 2170
```

Comment: You can use `<table>` to display this.

Comment: dear in which table define the table of format which display like i want.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f82e9a/data-displaying-in-table-format-in-diffrent-ways-in-mvc/).

Comment: It's better to show expected output based on inputs mentioned. For example, your expected output should have 0 qty for H&S1 in March 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a View Model for this and aggregate by introducing a new property :

```
public class SomeVM
{

   public int CustId { get; set; }    
   public int Jan { get;set; }
   public int Feb { get;set; }
   public int Mar { get;set; }
   public int Total { get { return Jan + Feb + Mar;}  }

}
```

and then in your linq query:

```
.Select(g => new SomeVM {
                CustId = g.Key,
                Jan = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 1).Sum(c => c.Qty),
                Feb = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 2).Sum(c => c.Qty),
                March = g.Where(c => c.OrderDate.Month == 3).Sum(c => c.Qty)
            });
```

You can even improve your linq query using `GroupBy` on `Month` property.

A more better approach can be to introduce an Enum for month:

```
public class SomeVM
{

   public int CustId { get; set; }    
   public List<FuelQuantity> FuelQuantities { get; set; }
   public int Total { get; set; }

   SomeVM()
   {
      FuelQuantities = new List<FuelQuantity>();
   }

}
```

and the FuelQuantity would look like:

```
public class FuelQuantity
{
   public FuelMonth Month { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

while your FuelMonth would look like:

```
public enum FuelMonth : int
{
   January = 1,
   February = 2,
   ..........
   ..........
}
```

Your linq query will also need to be adjusted to populate that collection and can then populate the Total.

Comment: Readability of the code could be improved by defining an enum so a month would refer to this enum, instead of remembering that 1 == Jan, don't you think?

Comment: I am afraid, as soon as you have data for additional months you are bound do change your code. This applies to this as well as OP's code. In your case there is an additional change, that is in VM.

Comment: agreed with both of you, there are multiple things OP can improve, but i am addressing the current problem actually being faced